# How do I include an external code file in Jenkins Workflow

Tags: groovy, jenkins, workflow

I'm trying to include external code in my Workflow script but I'm missing something.  The first step seems to work.  If the path is invalid this fails:

```
evaluate( new File('/home/larry.fast/Wkflo.groovy'))
```

But I've tried a number of syntactic variations on the following and haven't found an incantation that works.  All attempts have produced variants on "unable to resolve class mycode.Wkflo.

```
def z = mycode.Wkflo()
```

Wkflo.groovy contains:

```
package mycode;
def hello() {
  echo "Hello from workflow"
}
```

I've also tried variations like run(File()) or removing the package declaration.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Jenkins Workflow documentation now includes a section on "Loading Script Text"
https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md but I found it hard to follow.  Here's a simple example that demonstrates how to create complete workflows and other methods in external files.

Workflow code in Jenkins:

```
// Loading code requires a NODE context
// But we want the code accessible outside the node Context
// So declare extcode (object created by the LOAD operation) outside the Node block.
def extcode 

node {
    // paths are relative to your workspace
    // you may need to run git to populate your workspace
    git url: 'ssh://mygitrepo'
    extcode = load 'myExtCode.wkflo'

    // or you can directly access the file system
    // Eg. when developing your code in a local git clone
    extcode = load '/some/absolute/path/myExtCode.wkflo'

    // extcode is now a groovy object containing everything declared in the file
    extcode.hello('world')
}
// If your code contains Stage and Node blocks, 
// you'll want to initiate that code outside of the node() block above
extcode.extMain()
```

------ myExtCode.wkflo

```
// Any command placed at the root of the file get executed during the load operation
echo "hello from loading myExtCode"

// Methods declared in external code are accessible
//   directly from other code in the external file
//   indirectly via the object created by the load operation
//   eg.  extcode.hello('use this syntax from your main code')
def hello(whom) {
    echo "Hello ${whom}"
}

// Complete workflows should be created inside a controlling method
// else they will run nested inside the node() block when the load takes place (edit: added missing "def" keyword
def extMain() {
    stage 'External Code is running'
    node() {
        hello('from external node block')
    }
}

// !!Important Boilerplate!!     
// The external code must return it's contents as an object
return this;
```

Comment: Excellent example, this helped me a lot today, thanks :)